# User very rarely marks an answer as the accepted one

Tags: discussion, etiquette, accept-rate

I have come across a user that very rarely accepts answers even though most of his  questions have several answers, some of which are correct and address the user's question more than adequately.

I understand that it sometimes happens that none of the answers are adequate but this is clearly not the case.

Why would someone not choose one of the answers as the accepted one when his question is answered?

Should moderators be allowed to do something about this? For example, ask users to accept an answer before posting additional questions.

Should there be a minimum acceptance ratio?

Comment: Other users can request this person to accept answers.  But moderators should do nothing.

Comment: Why worry about such? The choice of accepted answer seems to often be as random as is voting in general, so it has little value.

Comment: Also: [Question on users that don't accept answers.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/15204), [Is it okay to never accept any answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17270), [Is it wrong to ask a user to accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6984),...

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat The first post is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I will add that there is a [comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4945#4945) which you can use if you want to tell a user about accepting answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe we can make that sort of software change. Compare this on the main StackExchange meta: [Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) - they seem to not care about accept rates. You could take their approach. If you do care about accept rates, the best thing IMHO is to leave polite comments reminding the user about accepting answers, and not writing answers to their new questions in the meantime.